# Get Component's Parent Form

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, components

I have a non-visual component which manages other visual controls.

I need to have a reference to the form that the component is operating on, but i don't know how to get it.

I am unsure of adding a constructor with the parent specified as control, as i want the component to work by just being dropped into the designer.

The other thought i had was to have a Property of parent as a control, with the default value as 'Me'

any suggestions would be great

**Edit:**

To clarify, this is a **component**, not a **control**, see here :[ComponentModel.Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[It is important to understand that the ISite technique below only works at design time.  Because ContainerControl is public and gets assigned a value VisualStudio will write initialization code that sets it at run-time.  Site is set at run-time, but you can't get ContainerControl from it]

[Here's an article](http://www.wiredprairie.us/journal/2004/05/finding_the_component_containe.html) that describes how to do it for a non-visual component.

Basically you need to add a property ContainerControl to your component:

```
public ContainerControl ContainerControl
{
  get { return _containerControl; }
  set { _containerControl = value; }
}
private ContainerControl _containerControl = null;
```

and override the Site property:

```
public override ISite Site
{
  get { return base.Site; }
  set
  {
    base.Site = value;
    if (value == null)
    {
      return;
    }

    IDesignerHost host = value.GetService(
        typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
    if (host != null)
    {
        IComponent componentHost = host.RootComponent;
        if (componentHost is ContainerControl)
        {
            ContainerControl = componentHost as ContainerControl;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If you do this, the ContainerControl will be initialized to reference the containing form by the designer.  The linked article explains it in more detail.

A good way to see how to do things is to look at the implementation of Types in the .NET Framework that have behaviour similar to what you want with a tool such as Lutz Reflector.  In this case, System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider is a good example to look at: a Component that needs to know its containing Form.

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine after a few minor tweaks (added some != null checks to it).

Comment: What exactly is service, it's not any member of the component.

Comment: I think `service` is actually supposed to be `host` - I switched it, and it's working for me so far.

Comment: How does this work at runtime. As far as i can see it is the designer that provides the IDesignerHost implementation, hence it only works in design mode.

Comment: It looks like this solution works when component is in separate assembly, not as part of the same project

Comment: I'm so sorry. That code working correct after drop component to the from, designer generate intialization code to the ContainerControl property! So to use that solution you shoud redrop component to the from.

Comment: @JonathanWood - "Doesn't work for me. host is always null" - is this true at design-time, after adding the component to a form in the designer?

Comment: @Joe: Hmmm... I guess I didn't test that. I'd have to set it up again to verify but I don't recall any errors at design time. I was mostly just testing at run time.

Comment: It seems hat I can not access parent form WindowState property with this example.

Comment: @eomeroff - I don't understand your comment: there's nothing in this example that attempts to access a parent form's WindowState property.  If you have similar code that tries and fails to do so, and you don't understand why, maybe you could post a new question with your example code.

Comment: Hi. It will add ContainerControl property value after drop control on form. But the value is correctly assign only in design-time, in run-time is null. So, definitely is not the solution of this problem!

Answer (score 9):

I use a recursive call to walk up the control chain. Add this to your control.

```
public Form ParentForm
{
    get { return GetParentForm( this.Parent ); }
}

private Form GetParentForm( Control parent )
{
    Form form = parent as Form;
    if ( form != null )
    {
        return form;
    }
    if ( parent != null )
    {
        // Walk up the control hierarchy
        return GetParentForm( parent.Parent );
    }
    return null; // Control is not on a Form
}
```

**Edit:** I see you modified your question as I was typing this. If it is a component, the constructor of that component should take it's parent as a parameter and the parent should pass in this when constructed. Several other components do this such as the timer.

Save the parent control as a member and then use it in the ParentForm property I gave you above instead of this.

Comment: You can also use Control.FindForm() to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to set the parent container some how.  Your component is just a class, that resides in memory just like everything else.  It has no true context of what created it unless something tells you that it did.  Create a Parent control property and set it.

Or simply derive from control and use FindForm().  Not all controls must have a visible component

Answer (score 2):

If the componenet is managing other visual controls, then you should be able to get to the parent through them.

Comment: I had thought of this, while it works, it does seem a little 'hacky'

Comment: I don't disagree with you, however if this component will always be tied to the controls of the same form that it's on, then you have nothing to lose.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20938/How-to-Get-a-Reference-to-Parent-Form-from-a-Compo) which does not need the input. For C# I implemented it this way:

```
public partial class RegistryManager : Component, ISupportInitialize
{

    private Form _parentForm;
    public Form ParentForm
    {
        get { return _parentForm;  }
        set { _parentForm = value; }
    }

    // Etc....

    #region ISupportInitialize
    public void BeginInit() {  }
    public void EndInit()
    {
        setUpParentForm();
    }
    private void setUpParentForm()
    {
        if (_parentForm != null) return; // do nothing if it is set
        IDesignerHost host;
        if (Site != null)
        {
            host = Site.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
            if (host != null)
            {
                if (host.RootComponent is Form)
                {
                    _parentForm = (Form)host.RootComponent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This way allows the set ParentForm by user, but it is set by parent form as Default.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Does this actually work for you? For me, `host` is always set to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This ....

```
private Form GetParentForm(Control parent)
{
    if (parent is Form)
        return parent as Form;

    return parent.FindForm();
}
```

Call `GetParentForm(this.Parent)` from component

Comment: Does not answer the actual question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the Site property of the IComponent. It's more or less an equivalent to the Parent property.

Comment: any chance you could be a little more specific please? i have had a look at the site property while debugging, and there seems to be nothing that references the parent form.

Answer (score -4):

A improvement of above is:

```
public static Form ParentForm(this Control ctrl) => ctrl as Form ?? ctrl.FindForm();
```

Answer (score -4):

If the component related `Form` is the active `Form` you may get it by `Form.ActiveForm`.