# Access Parent Form from a UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I have these properties on a form.

```cs
public enum LanguageID
{
    en, fr, de, it, ro
}

[Browsable(false)]
public Language[] Languages = new Language[]()
{
    new Language { LangID = LanguageID.en, TranslatedText = "One" },
    new Language { LangID = LanguageID.fr, TranslatedText = "Un"},
    new Language { LangID = LanguageID.de, TranslatedText = "Einer"}
    // and so on, for all other languages
}

public class Language
{
    public LanguageID LangID { get; set; } = LanguageID.en;
    public string TranslatedText { get; set; } = "One";
}
```

In design-time, user can change `LanguageID` property.
I added some custom `Control` objects on my form. In those objects constructors I want to access form's public property `Languages`, to be able to set a property of my custom controls according to selected `LanguageID` from form's property.

I've tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371464/get-components-parent-form) post, but `Site` property will be set only in design-time, not in runtime. In runtime `Site` property is null.

```cs
public ContainerControl ContainerControl
{
  get { return _containerControl; }
  set { _containerControl = value; }
}
private ContainerControl _containerControl = null;

// Custom object constructor
public MyControl()
{
    var langID = ((Form)ContainerControl).LanguageID; // the problem is here, ContainerControl is populated in DesignMode, but not in runtime. In runtime it's value is null
    var selectedLang = Array.Find(Form.Languages, l => l.LangID = langID);
    // code to set text here
}

public override ISite Site
{
  get { return base.Site; }
  set
  {
    base.Site = value;
    if (value == null)
    {
      return;
    }

    IDesignerHost host = value.GetService(
        typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
    if (host != null)
    {
        IComponent componentHost = host.RootComponent;
        if (componentHost is ContainerControl)
        {
            ContainerControl = componentHost as ContainerControl;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If this is not the good approach, please, I need some advice.

Comment: Reading this I'm not completely clear on exactly what the problem is, maybe you can clarify.  What I understand is that you're developing a user defined form and need a reference to the form's `Language` property, which is selected by the user of the form when they include it in their own project. You haven't been able to figure out how to determine at run-time which Language was selected and need a suggestion about how to get that information.

Comment: Exactly @ChristopherHamkins. I don't know if it is a good approach, but is what I think about . Maybe there is another way of doing that. But, as a conclusion, all my custom controls, which have the property `x` must access Language property of form to be able to set its own language text.

Comment: @ValiMaties said, "In those objects constructors I want to access form's public property `Languages`". I think what you really want is to `pass in` the Form's `Language` value to the constructor of the UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

Each controller has a parent object and you can use the following code to get the form:

```
Type type = this.Parent.GetType();
Control x = this.Parent;
while (type.BaseType.Name != "Form")
{
    x = x.Parent;
    type = x.GetType();
}
// HERE x is your form
```

Or as a method:

```
public Form GetParentForm()
{
    Type type = this.Parent.GetType();
    Control x = this.Parent;
    while (type.BaseType.Name != "Form")
    {
        x = x.Parent;
        type = x.GetType();
    }
    return (Form)x;
}
```

The loop is needed because your control might be inside another container inside of the form.

Comment: In Control's Constructor, Control.Parent is null. It's not working.

Comment: Do not use it in constructor. Add my method in the control and use it in any method that you want to get the parent Form.

Comment: Yes, seems moving code from Constructor to a method, worked.
Thanks.
I don't have reputation to accept your answer!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.